# Analytics Ecommerce, transactions not registering

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to record transactions in Analytic's Ecommerce module. They're not registering however and I don't know why. Page tracking happens at the top of the page:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22238012-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

and just prior to Ecommerce code, I'm tracking an event.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Conference', 'Signup', '1']);
```

Both an event and page tracking appear in Analytics, however this bit doesn't.

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    "26", // transaction ID - required
    "", //store name                
    "5160", // total - required
    "0", //tax
    "0.0", //shipping
    "", //city
    "", //state
    "DK"              // country
]);

            _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    "26", // transaction ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
    "1", // SKU/code - required
    "Paid Attendant", // product name                
    "", //category                
    "3195", // unit price - required
    "1"               // quantity - required
]);
            _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    "26", // transaction ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
    "3", // SKU/code - required
    "Extra Material", // product name                
    "", //category                
    "1965.00", // unit price - required
    "1"               // quantity - required
]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers
```

Do you have any idea as to why not?

Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. It took nearly more than a day for my transaction to appear, but it's there now.
The recorded transaction ids are exactly the ones that I tried yesterday. So the above example actually works.